# How to get multiple Via headers SIPP script?

Tags: regex, sip

In my scenario UAS receives two Via headers. Using [last_Via:] it replies 183, 200 OK for subsequent PRACK but for 180 Ringing and 200 OK for the original INVITE it needs those two Via headers. How do I store them in a variable so that I can use here ?

Approach that I goggled:

```
<ereg regexp="[Vv][Ii][Aa][        ]*:[    ](.*)$"  search_in="msg"  check_it="true"  assign_to="1"/>
```

*$1= It has both the Via headers but also the rest of the message including SDP.*

Answer (score 3):

```
<nop>
    <action>
        <assignstr assign_to="1" value="[last_Via:]" />
    </action>
</nop>
```

Otherwise, using your regex approach, you should be able to consume everything until the next CR LF characters with something like: `"[^\r\n]*\r\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this right before your `<send>`:

```
<nop>
  <action>
    <assignstr assign_to="lvia" value="[last_Via:]" />
    <ereg regexp="[Vv][Ii][Aa]: (.*), (.*)" search_in="var" variable="lvia" assign_to="5,6,7"/>
    <exec command="echo Via1: [$5], via2: [$6], via3: [$7]"/>
  </action>
</nop>
```

Then use the values store in variables 6 and 7.

This works for 2 Vias, you may need to adapt if you need to handle more.